# Counting number of images from loop

Tags: custom-field, loop, advanced-custom-fields

Im currently showing some data from a loop and loading a template:

```
<?php $index = 0; if ( have_rows('sections', get_option('page_for_posts') ) ) : while ( have_rows('sections', get_option('page_for_posts')) ) : the_row(); $index++; ?>
    <?php get_template_part('parts/section', get_row_layout() ); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Within the template how do I make a loop count depending on each loop of image? - I currently have:

```
<?php if ( $image = get_sub_field('image') ) : ?>
    <div class="inner">
        Image [loopcount]
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So lets say 3 images exists from in the loop, then im looking to print out:

```
<div class="inner">
    Image 1
</div>
<div class="inner">
    Image 2
</div>
<div class="inner">
    Image 3
</div>
```

Comment: This would be related to ACF. `get_sub_field` is an ACF function and the logic depends is their own. So I would recommend checking with their documents/forum to see if you could get the image count from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get images with foreach loop but first you have to print_r($images) and then get the value of the array something like this **$images['image']** or **$images['src']** or **$images['url']** etc. But first check is there any record where you are getting **get_sub_field('image')** all images.

```
<?php if ( $images = get_sub_field('image') ) :
    print_r($images);
    foreach($images as $image) {
?>
    <div class="inner">
        <?php
            echo $image;
        ?>
    </div>
<?php } endif; ?>
```